# How to make a pixelized image

Tags: images, pixel, raster

I have an image and i want to convert it to a pixel image where the pixels are definite in it! I want to it be like this:

[image: pixelated image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! Could you please be a little more specific? What software do you have access to? Can you show us some pictures of what you hope to achieve and what you have tried?

Comment: Hi AmiR, thanks for the added information. In the future please edit it into your question instead of posting it as an answer. You can do so by clicking the [edit] button

Answer (score 3):

Open Photoshop → Filter → Pixelate → Mosaic and just adjust pixel size to fit your needs.

In order to achieve image like that you will first need to generate black and white image where the silhouette is defined. After that apply method I described above. After that use Accented Edges filter from Filter Gallery to make white edges. Just turn smoothness to zero and its pretty much it.